# Get all matches using regexp preg_match() function in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to search for img elements in an xml with a specific src or href pattern. Examples: `< img  src= "level1/level2/2837"`, `< img  href ='level1/level2/54322'`.

```php
preg_match('/< *\/? *' // Begining of xml element
  . 'img' // "img" atribute
  . '[^>]*' // Any character except >
  . '(?:src|href) *= *' // src or href attribute with possible spaces between =
  . '(?:"|\')level1\/level2\/(\d+)(?:"|\')/', // "level1/level2/2837"
  $subject, $matches);
```

It works but only returns the first match.

For example if subject has this content:

```php
$subject = "< img  src= 'level1/level2/2837'/> <p>something</p> < img  href ='level1/level2/54322'";
```

The result I get is:

```php
$matches => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => '< img  src= "level1/level2/2837"' 
        [1] => '2837' 
    )
```

How can I get all the matches in `$matches` array?

I've already used [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to achieve this but would like to understand how regular expressions work with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: @AvinashRaj ok.. You're right that will match a single character thanks. I'm updating it

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn `["|']` to `(?:"|')` . This `['|"]` would match `'` or `|` or `"`. And also you need to use `preg_match_all` in-order to do a global match.

```
preg_match_all('/< *\/? *'
  . 'img'
  . '[^>]*'
  . '(?:src|href) *= *'
  . '(?:"|\')level1\/level2\/(\d+)(?:"|\')/', 
  $subject, $matches);
```